# Best way to get data from observables on page load?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

If I know all of the possible values of my api parameters when the pages is loading, is it better to try to load all of these values at once into a map on page load like so? Will the constructor ensure that all of the values will be set into the map?

The this.apiService.get(possibleQuery) returns an observable.

```
export class DataService {
  private queryMap: Map<string, string>;
  private possibleQueries = [
    'query1',
    'query2',
    'query3',
    'query4'
  ];

  constructor() {
      this.createQueryMap();
    }

  displayData(query: string) {
    console.log(queryMap.get(query));
  }

  private createQueryMap() {
    this.queryMap = new Map<string, string>();
    for (const possibleQuery of this.possibleQueries) {
      this.apiService.get(possibleQuery)
      .subscribe(result => { this.queryMap.set(possibleQuery, result); });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not correct to subscribe() in a service. It breaks the separation of concerns and it's not a good practice according to the observer design pattern. I would love to help more and suggest a solution, but can please elaborate more? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to invoke the apiService multime times?

Comment: the apiService is not something I can change, but retrieves a specific string value for a string request. On my page component, I need to display the result string based on a user action which takes a string query as input. So is it better to just run the apiService per user action directly from the page component? This would mean making unnecessary api calls if we have to do it more than once

Comment: now I got you :) Yes it's preferable to run the apiService per user action. It might seem that it will make more requests. But, think the other way around. What if the user wants only to perform one action? If you combine all the actions together you consume resources with no reason

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip). It will run all observables and emit one response in the subscribe once they are all done.

About the constructor "ensur[ing] that all of the values will be set into the map?"
The constructor is the first thing run in the class, but it won't halt the execution of other code while the API calls are being run.

If you need the API calls before your application completes it's initialization, you need to set up an [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the service be as clean as it is possible.

Something like

```
getByValue(value: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.apiService.get(value)
}
```

Let me elaborate:

Let's assume that the user has two actions

- Action 1
- Action 2

Those actions could be different span elements, like

`<span>Action 1</span>`
and
`<span>Action 2</span>`

If the user clicks on any action then you will invoke a method in your component. Say `actionClick` method. So, the `span` elements will become

```
`<span click="actionClick('action1')">Action 1</span>`
```

The **actionClick** method will invoke the method from your service and you will persist the result in an observable variable i.e. `value$`

```
actionClick(value: string) {
    this.value$ = getByValue(value)
}
```

Then you will have to display in the templating the value$ along with an **async** pipe

```
<p>
 The result is: {{value$ | async}}
</p>
```